# conflict between kbordermatrix and arydshln

Tags: incompatibility, arydshln

When I include `arydshln`, I get a conflict with `kbordermatrix` (from [here](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.sty)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\kbordermatrix{ &1 & 2 & 3\\ 
               a&b & c & d}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\adl@@cr ...tempdima \xdef \adl@rowsL {\adl@rowsL 
                                                  (\adl@colsL /\number \adl@...
l.11 \end{align}
```

How can I use both packages without conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't need to use dashed lines inside a `kbordermatrix`, you can obtain the same result with the `blockarray` environment – in a less simple way (but you may define new commands/ environments), and it is compatible with `arydshln`  as long as you don't use inside blockarray.

So I propose this code as a work-around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{array, blkarray} %

\usepackage{arydshln}

\newcolumntype{$}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{blockarray}{*{3}{>{\scriptstyle}c}}
 1 & 2 & 3\\
\begin{block}{\Left{$ \scriptstyle a $\enspace }{[\enspace}ccc\Right{. \enspace]}{}}
 b & c & d\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{$c*{3}{^c}}
\rowstyle{\scriptstyle} & 1 & 2 & 3\\
 \hdashline
\scriptstyle a & b & c & d 
\end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I use `blockarray` as a `kbordermatrix` substitute if I want to have multiple lines, e.g. `a | b c d` followed by `e | f g h` in the next line

Answer (score 1):

If you need features of both `arydshln` and `kbordermatrix`, I suggest you to use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{cc:cc}[first-row,first-col,last-row,last-col]
    & C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 \\
L_1 & 0   & 1   & 2   & 3   & L_1 \\
L_2 & 4   & 5   & 6   & 7   & L_2 \\
\hdottedline 
L_3 & 8   & 9   & 10  & 11  & L_3 \\
L_4 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15  & L_4 \\
    & C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

The previous code has created dotted rules (with rounded dots). If you prefer dashed rules, you have only to load TikZ and use the style `dashed` of TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|[tikz=dashed]cc}[first-row,first-col,last-row,last-col,margin=1pt]
    & C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 \\
L_1 & 0   & 1   & 2   & 3   & L_1 \\
L_2 & 4   & 5   & 6   & 7   & L_2 \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
L_3 & 8   & 9   & 10  & 11  & L_3 \\
L_4 & 12  & 13  & 14  & 15  & L_4 \\
    & C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Answer (score 0):

There are problems using `arydshln` and `\kbordermatrix`. Moreover you need to use the `\kbordermatrix` in the equation (According to the relevant [document](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/TeX/kbordermatrix.pdf) from Caltech).
Having said that, it does not deny the conflict among these packages.
you can try [easybmat package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat) instead of [arydshln](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/arydshln?lang=en) in some cases.

Comment: I can't compile this code either.